# dynamixel wheel_mode

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everybody,
i am new in ros and need to control 2 dynamixels (mx28r and mx106r).
in the standard_mode the actuators rotate 360°. i read that in the wheel_mode its possible to use the dynamixels as normal motors.
i already install the packages, but i cant find any information about it.
do anybody know how i can switch the cases.
thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59872/dynamixel-wheel_mode/) by [rossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4597/rossi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there ! ...

you can set dynamixel motor in wheel mode with its manager software ...
then there is a problem in ROS dynamixel package , you cant change rotation direction with set_speed service ! .

first download dynamixel stack packages from git , then use the function like this ...

```
def set_speed(self, speed):
        mcv = (self.motor_id, speed)
        self.dxl_io.set_multi_speed([mcv])
```

from joint_position_controller.py .

be aware change the speed service type from float64 to int32 , and then new range is

```
0 - 1023 CW
1024 - 2048 CCW
```

also the input is not radian / s speed ! , its dynamixel raw input then .

---

Originally posted by [edwin.babainas](https://answers.ros.org/users/10771/edwin.babainas/) with karma: 26 on 2014-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1